# Display items from string list every two seconds in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

Inside BlazorApp Index page I have a function in which I am adding strings to a list like this:

```
public List<string> consol { get; set; } = new List<string>();
 public void SecondMain()
            { 
                consol.Add("Some text1"); 
                consol.Add("Some text2");
                ...
            }
```

Then I display each string added to the list:

```
<button @onclick="SecondMain" class="btn btn-primary">Display</button>
@foreach (var item in consol)
                {
                  <p>item</p>
                }
```

It works fine. However, all strings appear in view at once. Is there a way to make them appear every few seconds?

Comment: Not specific to blazor, but check out Thread.Sleep()

Comment: No, avoid Sleep().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@onclick` supports async handlers:

```
public async Task SecondMain()
{ 
    consol.Add("Some text1"); 

    await Task.Delay(1000);  // 1 sec
    consol.Add("Some text2");
    StateHasChanged();

    await Task.Delay(1000);  // 1 sec
    consol.Add("Some text3");     
}
```

You will need a StateHasChanged(); for all but the first and last string. Add Task.Delay() as you like.

Comment: It makes sense, however seems, I do not know how to implement StateHasChanged(); Will check for namespaces, now getting this error:
```Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()' Tests.Client C:\Users\tom\source\repos\Tests\Tests\Client\Pages\Tasks\Objects1.razor 119 Active````

Comment: The you have a simple syntax error somewhere, hard to tell from here.

Comment: My SecondMain should be Ok, leave the @foreach and button as in the original post.

Comment: StateHasChanged(); shows in red, maybe it's because I have this function inside a class?

Comment: It works as you suggested. So I will mark as solved. However, I wonder why StateHasChanged does not work inside a class? Like if i had instead only SecondMain function something like onclick="SomeClass.SecondMain". if I put stateHasChanged inside that SomeClass method it shows as red.

Comment: Because @code is generated as a derived class of CompinentBase. You could supply the Component as `this` to the clas in some way but this is frontline UI code, I wouldn't bother.